# How to tell which rows toggle switch was changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uiswitch

I have a tableview with the accessoryview of a toggle switch.  I specify the section and the row and am having a difficult time determining which row was toggled.  I used the toggleSwitch.tag to grab the indexRow but as my indexRow is part of an indexPath.section I am not sure how to tell which row I toggled.

Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell;

Category *cat = [allCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
Subject *sub = [cat.subjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell = [[[SBTableAlertCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
UISwitch *toggleSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
cell.accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:toggleSwitch.frame];
[cell.accessoryView addSubview:toggleSwitch];

cell.textLabel.text =sub.title;   
cell.detailTextLabel.text = sub.category_title;

if (sub.active==1){
    [toggleSwitch setOn:YES];
} else {
    [toggleSwitch setOn:NO];
}

toggleSwitch.tag = indexPath.row;

[toggleSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(viewButtonPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[toggleSwitch release];

return cell;

}


- (void)viewButtonPushed:(id)sender {
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;    
UITableViewCell *cell = button.superview; // adjust according to your UITableViewCell-subclass' view hierarchy
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

Category *cat = [allCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
Subject *sub = [cat.subjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

selectedSubject = sub;

UISwitch* switchControl = sender;
NSLog( @"The switch is %@", switchControl.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF" );

if(switchControl.on){
    [sub setActive:1];
    NSLog(@"%@ is being set to ACTIVE", selectedSubject.title);
}else{
    [sub setActive:0];
    NSLog(@"%@ is being set to INACTIVE", selectedSubject.title);
}

[sub setIsDirty:YES];

[cat.subjects replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:sub];

[sub autorelease];
[cat autorelease];

}
```

Here is my didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  Do I need to have any reference to the toggleSwitch here?

```
- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Category *cat = [allCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
Subject *sub = [cat.subjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

selectedSubject = sub;
NSLog(@"selectedSubject = %@", selectedSubject.title);


if (tableAlert.type == SBTableAlertTypeMultipleSelct) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableAlert.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    else
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

    [tableAlert.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

}
```

Comment: You know you do have to write the changes to disk if you're saving it in a plist or similar. Just because you changed the array doesn't change the file itself.

Comment: Yeah I do that later. In further debugging I found my problem was not in the saving to the array but in the identification of which row had the toggle switched.

Comment: See my answer here for a neat method of doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274494/how-to-know-the-uitableview-row-number/9274863#9274863

Comment: Thanks and this is way better.  Can you look at my edited post as I am still having trouble with this.

Comment: @jrturton 's solution is really good and flexible!

Answer (score 1):

I have found that you need to go to the superview of the superview of the item in the cell (assuming that the button or control is right off the root of the cell) in order to get the pointer to the cell.

Try this instead:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = button.superview.superview;
```

and see if the results are any better.  Check out my blog post on this for more information:

[Two superviews are better than one](http://www.dosomethinghere.com/2011/08/10/two-superviews-are-better-than-one/)