# Button in custom cell in dynamic table: how to know which row in action method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have a table of dynamic content. In the prototype cell I have a button. In that button's action method, how do I then determine which row's button was pressed?

(I know that, for example, in a segue method one can determine which row has been pressed by querying the selected path of the table view, but in this case, no row has actually been selected.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are of course ways of doing this using `tag`s, or storing an `indexPath` in your cell etc.

I prefer to use something similar to the following, which I think is cleaner than the above. You could add this to a category UITableViewController.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCellSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    if (subview) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableViewCellForCellSubview:subview];
        return [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableViewCellForCellSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    if (subview) {
        UIView *superView = subview.superview;
        while (true) {
            if (superView) {
                if ([superView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                    return (UITableViewCell *)superView;
                }
                superView = [superView superview];
            } else {
                return nil;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Edit with suggestion from @staticVoidMan:

More concise implementation:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableViewCellForCellSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    UIView *checkSuperview = subview.superview;

    while (checkSuperview) {
        if ([checkSuperview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            break;
        } else {
            checkSuperview = checkSuperview.superview;
        }
    }
    return (UITableViewCell *)checkSuperview;
}
```

Comment: Superview trickery! I would argue that this is a hack, which is the opposite of clean code.

Comment: and... will crash in iOS6 (_if anyone cares about it_)

Comment: Yes, it is superview trickery. I would argue that this is less hack-ey than using tags or associated objects though.

Comment: @staticVoidMan I was going to combine this method of finding the superview and set the tag on the table cell. In principle this seems to work fine, but what's the problem with it crashing iOS6 exactly?

Comment: @NeilCoffey : in iOS6, the immediate `superview` of the `button` is a `UITableViewCell` subclass. in iOS7, (_they changed things a bit_) the immediate `superview` of the `button` is a private class called `UITableViewCellScrollView` and the `superview` of this is the required `UITableViewCell`. So when you do `button.superview.superview` (_in iOS6_), it returns `UITableView` and crashes when you try to implement a `UITableViewCell` method on it (_i haven't tested his method but when I see `superview`, I get over cautious, but it looks like he's handling this case... does it crash in iOS6?_)

Comment: I've just tried it - this does work on iOS 6.

Comment: @JoeFryer : great, so you did handle it via `if ([superView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) { return (UITableViewCell *)superView;}`. nice work

Comment: Yep - it keeps going up the view hierarchy until it finds a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Ah OK this is what I'm doing: traversing up the hierarchy looking for a view of the right class. So it looks like I should be good!

Comment: Just for info, the immediate superview would actually be (should be) a `UITableViewCellContentView` in both cases; the next superview is a `UITableViewCellScrollView` on iOS 7 (this is missing on iOS 6), then a 'UITableViewCell'.

Comment: @JoeFryer : yeah, you're right. `UITableViewCellContentView` and then yada yada. But... that was the point. I only saw `superview` and didn't see the part where you handled the cases. Anyways... might i suggest an improvement? (_just for kicks_)

Comment: Yeah, I just thought I'd note that here for anyone reading. Of course, please do!

Comment: @JoeFryer : this? [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HdnsYfAL) ... the `while (true)` is potentially infinite (_if... you send a `UIView` that does not have a `UITableViewCell` `superview` in it's upper hierarchy. **But**... what're the chances, right? hehe_)

Comment: It will still break the loop once it reaches the top view in the hierarchy :) I like yours though, it's more concise. Edited.

Comment: @JoeFryer : well... i'd still prefer my _answer_ :P but your approach was pretty interesting. anyways...

Answer (score 1):

You could use tags, associated objects, or superview trickery.

Here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963192/getting-data-from-a-textfield-inside-a-prototype-uicollectionviewcell/22966470#22966470) that has all three answers.

## Tags

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MySpecialCell";
    MySpecialCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[MySpecialCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.mySpecialTextView.delegate = self;
    }
    cell.mySpecialTextView.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
    int rowOfTextViewThatJustChanged = textView.tag;
}
```

## Associated Objects

```
static NSString *const kIndexPathKey = @"indexPathKey";

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MultiSelectCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
        [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        cell.accessoryView = switchView;
    }

    UISwitch *switchView = (id)cell.accessoryView;
    [self setIndexPath:indexPath onSwitch:switchView];
    switchView.on = [self isIndexPathSelected:indexPath];

    id item = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = safePerformSelector(item, self.itemDescriptionSelector);
    return cell;
}

- (void)switchValueChanged:(UISwitch *)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathOfSwitch:sender];
    [self setRowSelected:sender.isOn atIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.delegate didSelectItem:[self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath selected:sender.isOn sender:self];
}

- (void)setIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath onSwitch:(UISwitch *)switchView {
    [switchView setAssociatedObject:indexPath forKey:kIndexPathKey];
}

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathOfSwitch:(UISwitch *)switchView {
    return [switchView associatedObjectForKey:kIndexPathKey];
}


@implementation NSObject (AssociatedObjects)

- (void)setAssociatedObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString *const)key {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void *)(key), object, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (id)associatedObjectForKey:(NSString *const)key {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void *)(key));
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Best approach:

```
-(void)buttonMethod:(UIButton *)sender event:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pointCurrent = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForItemAtPoint:pointCurrent];

    //...
}
```

---

PS: Provided you have done something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //...

    [cell.someButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(buttonMethod:event:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //...
}
```

Comment: Best is subjective, this approach has failed for me in the past with resizing tableviews.

Comment: @CrimsonChris : subjective indeed but i have never faced an issue with this. What was the exact case in which it failed for you? (_just curious_)

Comment: When using a table view that automatically scrolls the cell you just touched to the center.

Comment: @CrimsonChris : hm... i'll have to see this for myself. maybe you were scrolling before catching the point (_not sure but i'll test this_)

Comment: That's exactly what was happening. Didn't want to change that behavior. Went with associated indexpaths, hasn't let me down yet!