# Button in UItableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableview and i have to use button in it.Based on tableViewCell i have to perform differnt action for different cell.How to distinguish which cell's button is clicked?

Comment: Add them as subviews and set their tags equal to their indexPath's row.

Comment: Using tags is rubbish. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274494/how-to-know-the-uitableview-row-number for a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is set a tag for the button in cellforrowatindex delegate fo UITableViewCell and then you will have to check the tag for the same in the action of the button.

```
if(((UIButton *)sender).tag==someIntValue)
{
//your statement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the tag property of the UIButton to the cell's indexPath.row:

```
button.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then in your button selector method, you can do:

```
-(void)handleButtonClick:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
   indexPathRow = button.tag;
}
```