# Passing Multiple Argument in Method from TableView Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arguments

I know thare are many questions on this but i just search for the another way.

I have a Table View which include a BUTTON. When this button is press, i like to pass the `Two Arguments in that method`.

This two arguments are id & indexPath.row.

**How can I do this?**

Help me to solve this..

Thank you,

Comment: Show your implemented code

Comment: What Do you mean by... **Two Arguments in that method** ??

Comment: Why do you want to do so when you can get clicked button's `indexPath` simply.

Comment: check my answer here - [How to pass UITableView IndexPath to UIButton @selector by parameters in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936126/how-to-pass-uitableview-indexpath-to-uibutton-selector-by-parameters-in-ios/11936294#11936294)

Answer (score 1):

**1.** No need to pass two arguments in button's `@selector` to get `indexPath:`. The button itself is enough.

I have already given an answer here - [How to pass UITableView IndexPath to UIButton @selector by parameters in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936126/how-to-pass-uitableview-indexpath-to-uibutton-selector-by-parameters-in-ios/11936294#11936294)

**2.** If you want to that just for your knowledge and another way to do so then here is it.

Make a custom class of `UIButton`.

**MyButton.h**

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *indPath;
@end
```

**MyButton.m**

```
#import "MyButton.h"

@implementation MyButton
@synthesize indPath = _indPath;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
    // Initialization code
   }
   return self;
}
@end
```

And use this `button` instead of `UIButton`.

```
 MyButton *btn = [[MyButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0, 2.0, 200.0, 40.0)];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button-%d", indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Assign indexPath here
btn.indPath = indexPath;

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
```

**Note: Don't use UIButtonButtonWithType here.**

And this is the `clicked:` method

```
-(void)clicked:(MyButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sender = %@", sender);
    NSLog(@"sender indexPath = %@", sender.indPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Make a Subclass of UIButton and have the parameters you want to pass in it.
Example:

MyButton.h

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *urArg
```

MyButton.m

```
@implementation MyButton
@synthesize urArg;
```

Usage

```
MyCustomButton *urButton = [[MyCustomButton alloc] init];
urButton.urArg = @"YOUR ARGUMENT HERE";
[urButton addtarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//      Implementation Part of Selector
- (void)btnTapped:(id)sender {

               MyButton *btn= (MyButton*)sender; 
               argType *arg = btn.urArg;
}
```

In This way one can get multiple arguments.

For first argument you can `btn.tag = indexPath.row`. For second use custom btn.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

There's one easiest way,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
     [button setTitle:@"YourArgument" forState:UIControlStateDisable];
     [button setTag:indexPath.row];
     [button addtarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)btnTapped:(id)sender {
     UIButton *btn= (UIButton *)sender; 
     NSString *argument = [button titleForState:UIControlStateDisabled];
     int tagID = btn.tag;
}
```

Note, we're setting up argument into disable state, so only use this solution if you'll not going disable your button. If you stop interaction to the button, you can disable it using, `setUserInteractionEnabled` to `NO`.

Comment: What is need of `argument` here ? And again I'm saying that this code would no work in case of multiple sections.