# When the button in TableView cell pressed, how do I know the button of which row of cell pressed?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom TableView cell, and in that  there's a button.
The table view have many rows used the same custom cell.
Now if the button of one of the cells pressed. I want to know which row of cell the button is in?

Comment: You can set the button's tag property to the row index.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936126/how-to-pass-uitableview-indexpath-to-uibutton-selector-by-parameters-in-ios/11936294#11936294

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1). In this method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` , assign button with a `tag`.
For example:

```
cell.yourbutton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

(2). Add action for you button with same selector

```
[cell.yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

(3). Then

```
-(void)cellButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
}
```

Comment: the questioner need the row number not the button index , just modify your answer

Comment: if i make a custome cell and in code i set the button tag, are the button tag in different rows of cell have the same button tag or different?

Comment: Should be different.You use it to decide which button is clicked.

Answer (score -2):

You can define your custom property and you can use it like below:-

```
#define kCustomProperty @"CustomProperty"
```

Associate your object with that custom property like below

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(yourButton,kCustomProperty , yourCellIndexPath, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Get your data using the same property and object like below

```
NSIndexPath *yourCellIndexPath = (NSIndexPath *)objc_getAssociatedObject(yourButton, kCustomProperty);
```

Its a kind of custom property you can create by coding if you don't want to use tag.