# How to Change the label values with that particular tag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my table view i have multiple label its shows cost product.
[image]like this but when i click the quantity button i can get the quantity values ,but i don't know how to multiple the costlabel with particular cell[which quantity button is pressed].

**This is my code:**
[image]

```
 cell.lblCostPrice.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.btnQuantity.tag=indexPath.row;

        [cell.btnQuantity addTarget:self action:@selector(quantityView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
currnentValues=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[[arrGetProduct objectAtIndex:tagValue] integerValue]];
    cell.lblCostPrice.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[arrGetProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"price"],amount];
```

can any one please help me

In quanityView method i can get which quantity button is clicked

```
     -(void)quantityView:(UIButton *)click
        {
            tagValue=click.tag;

        }
```

Here i am getting Quantity Values

```
- (void)popoverListView:(DDialogList *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    countQuantity=[[quantityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue];
    [self.mTableView.tableView reloadData];
    [qtyView dismiss];
}
```

Comment: can you give me cell for row at index path method so i can because i think you open picker on button click?

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA its not a picker that is also tableview but pop up method is used...

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA i have edited my code please check..

Comment: ok than this table is programmatically created or doing staticly hide-show

Comment: i have updated my code as per your requirement..@JAYRAPARKA

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA You need  array to add the and update value for your Quantities. Thanks

Comment: ya i see but what you want to do i didn't get properly you want to set the quantity value to label??

Comment: no didn't set because when user selected the particular quantity in view then automatically that label values have to change that particular cell,i mean 10000*quantity @JAYRAPARKA

Comment: @ilesh can you explain that please how to do that....

Comment: @KishoreKumar you have two tableview in single view controller and you need to set both table object and put condition to select value for table and set the value in table using reload table .Thanks

Comment: @KishoreKumar you want to select quantitiy and than calculate the selected cost * quantity right??

Comment: YES @JAYRAPARKA you correct...

Comment: so you didn't get cost??

Comment: i just displayed in that label that is cost value,i get those values using nsinteger bro..@JAYRAPARKA

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA bro see my code i have updated my code ,cell for row at index path...

Comment: i can get the particular button clicked cell cost @JAYRAPARKA

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936126/how-to-pass-uitableview-indexpath-to-uibutton-selector-by-parameters-in-ios/11936294#11936294

Answer (score 0):

viewwithTag is a method on UIView not on UIViewController. You'll probably have to call it like this:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:71];
```

Comment: UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:tagValue];
    label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",total];

Comment: i tried as per your suggestion finally crashed @Akash Raghani