# CoreGraphics determining click position in simulator - undefined symbol for architechture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-graphics

I am working with dynamic table view. As was suggested in previous reply
([How to know the UITableview row number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274494/how-to-know-the-uitableview-row-number/9274863#9274863)) I try to use CGPoint.

```
CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView]; 
NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];
```

I get debugger error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGPointZero", referenced from:
      -[MessageTableViewController btnCall:] in MessageTableViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

what does it mean, that i386 is not supported or do I need to somehow set GCPointZero?

Thank you!

Comment: Link against the CoreGraphics framework.

Comment: It is linked as far as I can see...

Comment: My bad. It was in frameworks folder but not linked for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You have to **link against** the `CoreGraphics framework`.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing Coregraphics framework in your class like so

```
 #import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

`CGPointZero` is part of the `CoreGraphics` framework. So you've two ways to solve this.

1. You link against the `CoreGraphics` framework as @user529758 already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965941).

or

2. As the [documentation of `CGPointZero`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpointzero) says it's a shortcut for `CGPointMake(0,0)`:

> A point constant with location (0,0). The zero point is equivalent to CGPointMake(0,0).

So you could replace `CGPointZero` with `CGPointMake(0,0)`.