# How to get the indexPath of a UIButton in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableview` with multiple cells. On each cell I'm adding buttons dynamically according to some array count. So, when I click on a button I'm able to get the `tag` value of the button. But how to get the `indexPath` of that cell?

Here is my code in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
   UIView *view=(UIView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+444];

   UIImageView *img=(UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+999];
   img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"BHCS_empty.png"];

   if(integer!=50)
   {
        NSInteger y_axis=0;
        NSArray *Arr=[tableSubCategoryArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"BHCS_selected.png"];

        view.Frame= CGRectMake(0,50,281, integer-50);
        for (int i=0; i<[Arr count]; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"arr %@",[Arr objectAtIndex:i]);
            UIButton *Btn=[UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
            Btn.frame=CGRectMake(0, y_axis, 281, 44);
            [Btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BHCS_panel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Btn addTarget:self action:@selector(subCategoryBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [Btn setTag:i+100];
            [view addSubview:Btn];


            UILabel *nameLbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, y_axis,248, 44)];
            nameLbl.text = [[Arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"SubCategoryName"];
            nameLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            nameLbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            panelTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BHCS_panel_div1.png"]];
            nameLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0f];
            [view addSubview:nameLbl];

            y_axis=y_axis+44+1.3f;
        }
    }
```

Comment: An easy way to do this is create a UITableView extension.
See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39059239/3395921) to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks  to all  i slove this by using below code

```
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [panelTableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview.superview];

NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
```

Comment: in iOS8..this will always give 0. Please see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784630/how-to-find-indexpath-for-tapped-button-in-tableview-using-seque/27292570#27292570

Comment: Do not use this answer. It is wrong. Never assume a specific structure for the private view hierarchy.

Answer (score 29):

I have tried maximum of given answers, but at the and I generally use to go for most Generalised and ideal way as follows:

```
 CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
```

Comment: Super ...
In Swift


let hitpoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tablename)
let indexpath_select = self.Flight_detail_table.indexPathForRow(at: hitpoint)
print("indexpath: \(String(describing: indexpath_select))")

Answer (score 13):

ALLLLL of the answers here are bad and you shouldn't be looping through superviews. Classic example, with iOS 7 Apple changed the `tableViewCell` hierarchy and your app will now crash!

Use this instead:

[How to know the UITableview row number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274494/how-to-know-the-uitableview-row-number/9274863#9274863)

Comment: oh. This was such a short, link-only answer I almost missed, but it is actually really good. The point is that the button contains information about where it was on the screen, which can be readily converted to an index path.

Comment: Do you want to qualify "bad"?  A fixed dependency on [someView superview] might break over time (even if the whole view hierarchy is controlled by the app developer).  But looping up until one finds the table view cell is certainly safe now and in the future.

Answer (score 10):

**Updated answer**

Use it like:

```
CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView]; 
NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];
```

Comment: it is crashing at NSIndexPath *indexPath = [view indexPathForCell:cell];

Comment: Are you adding your button directly into cell? If not you need to go to superview till you reach cell like button.superview.superview and so on. Please check the type of cell while debugging, it will help.

Comment: NO, NO NO NO ! Just don't loop through superviews ! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274494/how-to-know-the-uitableview-row-number/9274863#9274863

Comment: i was getting the same thing. looks like in iOS 7, the hierarchy changed as apple added UITableViewCellScrollView: http://www.curiousfind.com/blog/646 so you need to add one more .superview. @CW0007007 that does work but only if you have the self.tableview property and my screen happens to have a whole bunch of tableviews making it trickier.

Comment: in iOS8..this will always give 0. Please see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784630/how-to-find-indexpath-for-tapped-button-in-tableview-using-seque/27292570#27292570

Comment: Do not use this code. Never assume such a subview hierarchy. It will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the button's action method:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [yourtableviewname indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview];
   NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
```

Comment: but everytime its retuning zeroth indexpath

Comment: in your code you are adding button to view that's why it gives 0 values means here sender.superview taken as view i think so.

Comment: hey i tried like this its working fine now in button action

Comment: in iOS8..this will always give 0. Please see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784630/how-to-find-indexpath-for-tapped-button-in-tableview-using-seque/27292570#27292570

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a property to your custom UITableViewCell implementation class to store the indexPath.  Then, when your cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate fires in your TableViewController, set the indexPath property for that cell.

customTableViewCell.h :

```
@interface customTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property NSIndexPath *indexPath;

@end
```

customTableViewController configure cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    customTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Do whatever you want with your cell
    cell.indexPath = indexPath;

    return cell;
}
```

Then you can refer to the indexPath property in your customTableViewCell by calling self.indexPath

Comment: No. do not do this. If the table view allows rows to be deleted, inserted, or moved, then the `indexPath` property of this custom cell will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers seem like a very clean solution. The way I would implement this is by using the delegate pattern. The view controller is the cell's delegate, meaning you let the cell itself handle the button press, and it tells its delegate when the button was pressed so it can handle it however it wants.

Let's say you have a tableview where each cell represents a `Person` object, and when the button is pressed you want to show a profile for this person. All you need to do is this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PersonCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.person = self.people[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)personCell:(PersonCell *)personCell didPressButtonForPerson:(Person *)person {
    [self showProfileForPerson:person];
}
```

Then all you need to do in your button class is add a property called `buttonPressedHandler` that is a block passing back an instance of `Person`, and when you create your button and add the target do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // do whatever whatever else you need/want to here

    [self.button addTarget:self selector:@selector(handleButtonPressed) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)handleButtonPressed {
    // Make sure this is a required delegate method, or you check that your delegate responds to this selector first...
    [self.delegate personCell:self didPressButtonForPerson:self.person];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `UITableView`'s `indexPathForCell:` method like so `[tableView indexPathForCell:cell];`. Good Luck!

Comment: where should i use this line?