# Pass into didSelectRowAtIndexPath when click on a UITableViewCell button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a simple *UITableView*, and each cell contains a button :
[image]

In my *didSelectRowAtIndexPath method*, I have the following code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Selected cell : %@", [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
}
```

**That I want :**

When I click **on a button** (which is in a cell), I want to **know what cell is selected**. My problem is that when I click on a button (just on the button, not in the cell), I don't pass into the *didSelectRowAtIndexPath method*, unfortunately, because the cell is not selected...

How can I do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the tag values of the uibutton in uitableviewcell and aswell cel indexPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229488/how-to-get-the-tag-values-of-the-uibutton-in-uitableviewcell-and-aswell-cel-inde)

Comment: I tried, but my cells are "custom cells", so I manage the button action in another class. I don't know how to get my tableView from another view... :s

Answer (score 1):

Make this, and you will have the index of UiCell selected!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    while (![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        view = [view superview];
    }
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)view];

  //Make everything that you want in here!!!!!!!
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention who 'view' actually is.

Answer (score 0):

that is pretty easy every time that you make a cell you set the `button.tag` like your index path when you click on the button you start to run your method like

```
- (IBAction)someMethod:(UIButton *)button
```

where button is the button clicked so you can get the tag and have the index :)

Comment: Is there any other method, without using the tags ?

Comment: @Erzékiel Yes, see the duplicate answer I referenced above.