# How do I change the UIImage of a UIButton that is a property of a custom UICollectionViewCell upon tap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell that holds a UIButton with an image set. The purpose of this bottom is to allow users who are shopping via the app to add items to a list of their favourite items.

I have 2 versions of the image. One is a default greyed out heart and the other is a black heart. When a user taps to add an item to their favourites this method is fired:

**Method fired on tap of heart:**

```
- (void)addToFavouritesButtonTapped
{
    NSLog(@"add to favourites button tapped");
}
```

**In my cellForItemAtIndexPath method for my UICollectionView I have this:**

```
    _addToFavouritesButton = [cell addFavouriteButton];
   [_addToFavouritesButton addTarget:_thisController action:@selector(addToFavouritesButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Upon tapping the heart to save an item to favourites I'd like the image to change to my highlighted version which is the black heart.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the other image as the one for the [`UIControlStateSelected`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW11) and then when the button is tapped set the button to [`selected`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW15)`= YES`, this will then change the image.

```
_addToFavouritesButton = [cell addFavouriteButton];   
[_addToFavouritesButton addTarget:_thisController action:@selector(addToFavouritesButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_addToFavouritesButton setImage:blackHeart forState:UIControlStateSelected];

- (void)addToFavouritesButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"add to favourites button tapped");
    sender.selected = YES;
}
```

Comment: How do I keep track of the selected button? Everytime I scroll it the cell with the newly updated heart isn't the one I originally modified.

Comment: You probably want something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274494/how-to-know-the-uitableview-row-number).
And you'll need some sort of store against favourited items which you can query in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the button state to show a different image. Check the documentation for UIButton, there is a method `setImage:forState:` that you can use to set an image for normal state, highlighted state, selected state.
You can even do it in Interface Builder.

On a side note, if you want to do something else with the button once it's pressed you should do the following:

**Append : to the selector**

```
[_addToFavouritesButton addTarget:_thisController action:@selector(addToFavouritesButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Receive the UIButton in the method**

```
- (void)addToFavouritesButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
```

Then you can manipulate the button in that method