# Want accessory checkmark to show only when tapped on the right

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a TableView with cells that when pressed anywhere in the cell, it adds a checkmark on the right. I only want the checkmark to show up if the cell is tapped on the right side. Here's the pertinent section of code from the TableViewController:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell

        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
            cell.task = task


        if task.completed {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark;
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none;
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

        var tappedItem = tasks[indexPath.row] as Task
        tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed
        tasks[indexPath.row] = tappedItem

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    }

}
```

Is there a simple way to do that, or to do it using storyboard? My Swift skills leave a LOT to be desired. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the built-in checkmark accessory type, why not provide, as accessory view, an actual *button* that the user can tap and that can display the checkmark? The button might, for example, display as an empty circle normally and as a circle with a checkmark in it when the user taps it.

Otherwise, you're expecting the user to guess at an obscure interface, whereas, this way, it's perfectly obvious that you tap here to mark the task as done.

Example:

[image]

To accomplish that, I created a button subclass and set the `accessoryView` of each cell to an instance of it:

```
class CheckButton : UIButton {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Georgia", size:10)
        self.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        self.check(false)
    }
    func check(_ yn:Bool) {
        self.setTitle(yn ? "✔" : "", for: .normal)
    }
    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The title of the button can be the empty string or a checkmark character, thus giving the effect you see when the button is tapped. This code comes from `cellForRowAt:`:

```
    if cell.accessoryView == nil {
        let cb = CheckButton()
        cb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.accessoryView = cb
    }
    let cb = cell.accessoryView as! CheckButton
    cb.check(self.rowChecked[indexPath.row])
```

(where `rowChecked` is an array of Bool).

Comment: I would love to do exactly that, in fact I really like the circles rather than boxes, but unfortunately I don't know how to do that programmatically.

Comment: Improved code to make the checkmark button more encapsulated.

Comment: My weak programming abilities are haunting me again! I'm getting 3 errors under cellForRowAt:
1. In the cb.addTarget line, "Use of unresolved identifier 'touchUpInside'"
2. In the cb.addTarget line, "Use of unresolved identifier 'buttonTapped'"
3. Value of type 'ListTableViewController' has no member 'rowChecked'" I guess I need to set up the rowChecked array somewhere? I'm not sure how to address errors 1 and 2 though.

Comment: You'd need to have a method `func buttonTapped` too.

Comment: I just ordered your book! Hopefully it helps me figure this out. Thanks matt, I think you've helped me on here before; you're a great resource!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to define your own accessory button, and handle its own clicks.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell

    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
        cell.task = task

    let checkButton = UIButtonSubclass()
    ...configure button with your circle and check images and a 'selected property'...
    checkButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonTapped(_:forEvent:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.accessoryView = checkButton
    checkButton.selected = task.completed //... this should toggle its state...

    return cell
}

func buttonTapped(_ target:UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    guard let touch = event.allTouches?.first else { return }
    let point = touch.location(in: self.tableview)
    let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForRow(at: point)
    if let task = tasks[indexPath.row] {
        task.completed = !task.completed
    }
    tableView.reloadData()   //could also just reload the row you tapped
}
```

<del>Though, it has been noted that using tags to detect which row was tapped is dangerous if you start to delete rows.  You can read more here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9274863/1189470</del>

**EDITTED**
Removed the reference to tags per @matt

Comment: Indeed. Then don't show this use of tags, since indeed it _is_ dangerous. Here's how I do it (this would be in your `buttonTapped`): `var r : UIView = sender; repeat {r = r.superview!} while !(r is UITableViewCell); let ip = self.tableView.indexPath(for: r as! UITableViewCell)!` Now we have the desired index path and can take its `row` as desired.

Comment: Fair point @matt - thought I'm less of a fan of iterating through UIKit view hierarchies, so I got less lazy and typed how I typically handle it!

Comment: Equally fair point. But gosh, I iterate thru view / responder hierarchies all the time. What on earth are they for if you can't do this? It's nothing but a linked list after all. Super fast, super efficient, tried and true.

Comment: Thanks dmorrow! I'm getting the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'event'". Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @BobF. - sorry, see my edits.  I was using the wrong signature for `buttonTapped`

Comment: @dmorrow Ok, that fixed the 'event' error, but now there's a "Value of optional type 'indexPath?' not unwrapped" error in the line "if let task = tasks[indexPath.row] {". Is there a way to guard that? Or should I address that another way?