# indexPathForSelectedRow returning wrong index

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, nsindexpath

I want to get the some of the data of what is displayed in a cell when I'm tapping on a button which I placed in the cell. For this I have implemented used the indexPathForSelectedRow method. But when I'm tapping on the cell, the method is returning 0 index, even if I'm not tapping on the 0th index cell. This is the code I used for the button -

```
- (IBAction)dataSaveLounge:(id)sender {

NSIndexPath *path = [self.loungeTable indexPathForSelectedRow];

NSString *titleSave = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"title"];

NSString *subtitleSave = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"excerpt"];

NSString *idSave = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"id"];


saveMdl = [FavouritesModel saveFavourites:titleSave and:subtitleSave and:idSave];

}
```

**EDIT : Added cellfForRowAtIndex Method**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *loungeCellID = @"MyCellLounge";
LoungeTableCell *loungeCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:loungeCellID];

if (loungeCell == nil) {

    loungeCell = [[LoungeTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCellLounge"];
}

loungeCell.loungeTitle.text = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"title"];
loungeCell.loungeSubtitle.text = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"excerpt"];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    loungeCell.loungeImgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]];

    [loungeCell.loungeImgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[loungeData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"banner_image"]]];
});

return  loungeCell;
}
```

I'm saving some data in core data on button click, hence the last method call

Comment: set button tag as indexPath.row, show cellForRowAtIndex method

Comment: Is `path` nil ??

Comment: @karthikeyan I'm editing my question and adding the cellForRowAtIndex method in it

Comment: @Larme I've mentioned in the question body, I'm getting 0 index

Comment: Are u clicking button or row?

Comment: @karthikeyan I'm clicking the button

Comment: LoungeTableCell contain button?

Comment: Make sure you have not set cell selection style to None.

Comment: Then if you are clicking the button how would you expect to get the IndexPath?

Comment: `NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil; NSLog(@"Row: %ld", [indexPath row]);` This logs "Row: 0". So, it's not clear in your question if in fact `path` is `nil`. Which could have a lot of sense, since your tap on the button, but who says that you select the cell? Is `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` called to verify that?

Comment: @AkshayYerneni, also confirm table view selection style to single selection.

Comment: you have selected the button but not the row! Hence indexPathForSelectedRow will not work in your case. You need to manually calculate the indexpath based on the button position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you are clicking button in row
**SET** button tag

```
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row 
[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(dataSaveLounge:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In your  **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (IBAction)dataSaveLounge:(id)sender {
UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
   NSLog(@"Tag of button pressed:%d",pressedButton.tag);
}
```

Comment: Why is there a need of creating a button inside -(IBAction)dataSaveLounge:(id)sender ? Shouldn't I use the button outlet I created in the tablecell class ?

Answer (score 0):

Set button tag in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

for e.g. `loungeCell.btn = indexPath.row;// set your button IBOutlet name here`

and then access here

```
- (IBAction)dataSaveLounge:(id)sender {

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;


    NSString *titleSave = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:btn.tag] valueForKey:@"title"];

    NSString *subtitleSave = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:btn.tag] valueForKey:@"excerpt"];

    NSString *idSave = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:btn.tag] valueForKey:@"id"];


    saveMdl = [FavouritesModel saveFavourites:titleSave and:subtitleSave and:idSave];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

Replace your `dataSaveLounge` method with below method:

```
- (IBAction)dataSaveLounge:(id)sender {

  CGPoint center= sender.center; 
  CGPoint viewPoint = [sender.superview convertPoint:center toView:self.loungeTable];
  NSIndexPath *path = [self.loungeTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:viewPoint];


  NSString *titleSave = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"title"];

  NSString *subtitleSave = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"excerpt"];

  NSString *idSave = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"id"];


  saveMdl = [FavouritesModel saveFavourites:titleSave and:subtitleSave and:idSave];

}
```

OR

```
- (IBAction)dataSaveLounge:(id)sender {

      CGPoint btnPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero
                                   toView:self.tableView];
      NSIndexPath *path = [self.loungeTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:btnPosition];



      NSString *titleSave = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"title"];

      NSString *subtitleSave = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"excerpt"];

      NSString *idSave = [[loungeData objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"id"];


      saveMdl = [FavouritesModel saveFavourites:titleSave and:subtitleSave and:idSave];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is risky to use tags for this purpose in a UITableView.  If you add or delete any rows, the tag will not change on existing visible rows, and you'll be pointing to the wrong index.

See this answer for a better solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/43036216/1189470

Answer (score 0):

You can also get `NSIndexPath` like this way. if you have multiple section than also this code help you. and make sure your button hierarchy in  `LoungeTableCell`

```
- (IBAction)dataSaveLounge:(id)sender {
     LoungeTableCell *cell = (LoungeTableCell *) sender.superview.superview;
     NSIndexPath *path =  [self.loungeTable indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```